# Can't compile the TPLINK TL-WN822N driver under Linux Mint 19.1 XFCE

Tags: gcc, makefile, linux-device-driver

I have an USB wifi adapter (TPLINK TL-WN822N. I downloaded the linux driver from the manufacturers [download page](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180514/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta.zip) and tried to compile it, but I always get errors when I try to run the make command.

I have a Linux Mint 19.1 with XFCE desktop. The `uname -a` gives the followings:

- Linux user-HomePC 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

My opinion is that the problem is caused by the gcc version.

I also have an LXLE linux installed in an old PC and the driver compilation can be done without any errors. And the installed driver is working perfectly.

- The Linux Mint has a
  gcc version: gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
  make version: GNU Make 4.1
- The Linux LXLE has a 
  gcc version: gcc version 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)
  make version: GNU Make 4.1

When I start the make command I get the following messages:

---

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/build M=/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service.h:47:0,
                 from /home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/drv_types.h:27,
                 from /home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.c:17:
/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service_linux.h:299:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/include/osdep_service_linux.h:300:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Asztal/rtl8192EU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-47-generic'
Makefile:1828: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

---

If I am right, and the problem is caused by the newer gcc version, then is there a way to use another version of gcc for casual compilation?

If something else is the problem, what could it be?

I am new in the Linux platform, and may be the answer is so profane, but some help would be really appreciated.

ps. And sorry for my English, is not my mother language ;

Comment: Just one more thing, in the installation guide I found:
The development environment in Ubuntu is required as follows:
Development Environment
OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS;
Kernel version 4.13.0-36-generic;
Gcc version 5.4.0

Comment: You probably do not need to build this old driver. Just do `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra linux-firmware`.

Comment: The problem isn't the gcc version. The problem is that the the driver source code has not been updated for the Linux kernel version you are using. You do not need it anyway as the device is already supported by the Linux kernel you are using, but the driver module is not installed by default. The required driver module ("rtl8xxxu.ko") is in the "linux-modules-extra" package. The driver needs to load a firmware file for the device. The required firmware file ("rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin") is in the "linux-firmware" package.

Comment: @Ian Abbott: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried the suggested command (sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra linux-firmware), but the answer was: no such package: linux-modules-extra. Or something like that (it was in hungarian). I also checked those packages in the synaptic package manager, and it seems they are already installed.

Comment: My original problem was that, when the system starts the adapter sometimes is able connect to the router and sometimes is not. In those cases I have to unplug it for a few seconds then replug and it is able to connect. I was searching the web about this problem and I read that I should download the driver from the manufacturers website. But, as I wrote, under the Linux Mint 19.1 can't compile that driver.

Comment: What I did now, I downloaded the linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-47-generic_4.15.0-47.50_amd64.deb package which is similar to my kernel version and the file you wrote (rtl8xxxu.ko) is the same what I have in my system directory. I also downloaded the linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-15-generic_4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1_amd64.deb and I found that the rtl8xxxu.ko file date is older than what I have in my system. My question is: should I overwrite my file with it or better to keep the one I have now in my system folder?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct - there is no package called `linux-modules-extra`. However, the `linux-image-generic` package will pull in the correct `linux-modules-extra-*` package for your kernel version as a dependency, which is why you already have it installed.

Comment: You should not overwrite the "rtl8xxxu.ko" module with one from a different kernel. They are compiled for a specific kernel and are very unlikely to load (and even less likely to work properly once loaded) for a completely different kernel version.

Comment: Thank you for your respond! So it means there is no solution for my original problem: to unplug and replug the device to have it work... By the way, thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

At least I found the solution with a little help. Here is what I did to get working my USB wifi adapter after system restart:

1. Check for updates: sudo apt update
2. Install the git: sudo apt install git
3. Download the driver from github: git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
4. Change to the driver directory: cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
5. Compile the driver for your kernel: make
6. Install the driver into the system: sudo make install
7. Load the driver: sudo modprobe 8192eu

But the procedure is not finished here, because the system will use the originally installed driver, so we have to blacklist it:

8. open the corresponding file: sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf
9. insert the blacklist option into the file: blacklist rtl8xxxu
10. save the file and exit
11. restart the system

Now it should work in the proper way. For me it worked.

Hope, it will help to someone...

Answer (score 0):

## Your system needed `rtlxxxu` Driver

I was facing the same issue in my Linux while using the TP-link wifi adapter.
To fix it, I've gone through many questions and GitHub discussions, and Finally, I found something working for my system.

Basically, I got a bunch of commands to execute to just fix this issue. But later I realize that there are many geeks out there who were facing the same issue. So, I prepared a script containing the whole commands altogether.

### Driver => [RTL8192U](https://github.com/mayurchhapra/education_theses/blob/master/rtl8192eu-linux.sh)

Please go to the above link `RTL8192u`, download the `sh` file, and execute it.
The Script will take care of your Driver.

Otherwise, you can manually copy all the commands and execute them. In Both ways, your issue will get fixed.